# Fortran symbol not in load table (unable to call loaded symbol in R)

Tags: r, dll, fortran

I am trying to build a Fortran DLL with Absoft Pro Fortran 13.0.3, 64 bits, for use within R, on Windows 7 64 bits.

Here is my file mycalc.f (it's a dumb example, just to test functionality):

```
subroutine mycalcf(a,b,c)
real*8 a,b,c
dll_export mycalcf
c=a+b*b
end
```

The statement `dll_export` is not standard, but is found in some Fortran compilers (AFAIK it's also found in Lahey and CVF and Intel Fortran has a compiler directive instead). It just tells the compiler which symbols are to be exported.

I compile successfuly with:
`af90 -m64 -dll -YDLL_NAMES=LCS mycalc.f -o mycalc.dll`

The option `-YDLL_NAMES=LCS` tells the compiler to build a library with lowercase symbols, which seems better for R.

If I run `dumpbin /exports mycalc.dll`, I can find mycalcf in exported symbols, in lowercase, without any underscore before or after.

Now, from R (64 bit version), the following works:

```
dyn.load("mycalc.dll")
is.loaded("mycalcf")
.Fortran("mycalcf", a=4, b=5, c=0)
```

I get c=29 on return, as expected.

**BUT**, if I restart R, the following does not work (notice I only removed the `is.loaded` test):

```
dyn.load("mycalc.dll")
.Fortran("mycalcf", a=4, b=5, c=0)
```

I get the error: `Fortran symbol name "mycalcf" not in load table`.

Now my question is: why is this test so important?

---

For comparison, when I try the same with gfortran instead of Absoft, I have no problem at all. I compile with: `gfortran -m64 -shared -o mycalc2.dll mycalc.f` (after commenting out the dll_export statement, which is not needed, nor even recognized, by gfortran).
Then in R:

```
dyn.load("mycalc2.dll")
.Fortran("mycalcf", a=4, b=5, c=0)
```

And I get c=29, no error.

Now, I suspect there is something the gcc linker does that is not done automatically by the Absoft linker (actually it's Microsoft's link.exe). But I have no hint what it can be.

Any idea is welcome!

---

Ok, solution after a good question from Vladimir F (see comments).
Actually, one must append underscores to symbol names. Since there is no way to do it by compiler option, one needs `CDEC$` directives (see [HP](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0586.htm) or [Intel](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/fortran/lin/lref_for/source_files/rfattals.htm) documentation).

Here it's simply:

```
      subroutine mycalcf(a,b,c)
CDEC$ attributes alias:'mycalcf_' :: mycalcf
      real*8 a,b,c
      dll_export mycalcf
      c=a+b*b
      end
```

Second solution, from [Absoft forum](http://absoft.absoft.com/newforums/index.php?topic=850.0): actually I was wrong from the very beginning. Contrary to what I thought, one need not use the dll_export statement, and it even introduced the problem: without it, the compiler appends underscores. All symbols are exported by default, as in gfortran. So the correct code is simply:

```
      subroutine mycalcf(a,b,c)
      real*8 a,b,c
      c=a+b*b
      end
```

There is even no need for any option to get lowercase symbols, it's also the defaults.

---

***However, one question remains: does the R function `.Fortran` always add underscore (is there a way to tell it not to?), and if it's always added, why does the call work when `is.loaded` is called beforehand? R seems to be doing something weird here.***
I tried to track `is.loaded` in R source code (up to `do_isloaded` in `src\main\dotcode.c`), to no avail.

Comment: Doesn't .Fortran actually append the trailing underscore automatically to the call?

Comment: gfortran does append the underscore, but not Absoft. There is a `-YEXT_SFX="_"` option to append it, but it does not work on DLL symbols. But, if I add the underscore manually in Fortran source, everything is fine in R. So it looks like it's this missing underscore that prevents R from seeing the symbol, and the `is.loaded` function somehow solves this problem. Is there a way to tell R to look for symbols without underscore?

Comment: I am not talking about the compiler, but about R's call.

Comment: Yes, and I finally found the solution thanks to your question :-) I believe `.Fortran` adds the underscore, but then I still doon't understand why I have no error when I call first `is.loaded`. However, I can have Absoft to add underscores as well, not by compiler option, but by compiler directive of the kind `CDEC$...`, found in some compilers (HP & Intel at least).

Comment: Thus I found the solution by reading [Intel](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/fortran/lin/lref_for/source_files/rfattals.htm) and [HP](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0586.htm) documentation, since there is apparently nothing in Absoft's doc on this (d'oh!). Thank you very much for your help!