# Shared objcect not loaded

Tags: r, fortran, shared-objects

I am trying to trigger a FORTRAN code from R.
For that I am creating a .so file by giving command 
`R CMD SHLIB filename.f`
The .so file is created without any warnings(!!)
To lead the file in R, I give the following command in R

```
dyn.load("filename.so")
```

The file gets loaded as it shows when I give command `getLoadedDlls()` in R.
But when I try to run it using `.Fortran("filename")` it throws an error

> Error in .Fortran("filename") :  Fortran symbol name "filename" not in
>   load table

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/q/18767463 ?  Essentially it's possible that the compiler will append an "_" (or two) to the end of the routine name. The `.Fortran` may attempt to add this automatically. There are various tools to show you the contents of a "dll" file so you can try to find out what name is actually used, such as http://stackoverflow.com/a/375284 This may help identify if the correct name is being used.

Comment: Sorry I realised you're using a `.so` extension so you're probably on linux, in which case you can try the `nm` command so see what symbols are present in the library.

Comment: Tried `.Call("filename")`?

Comment: nm filename.so gave me a bunch of output results.Like - " 00000000002067b8 d __CTOR_END__ " and a lot

Comment: Maybe you can try `readelf` (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/34732) or try `nm filename.so | grep -i X` where `X` is the routine name that you're trying to call.

Comment: @J_F .Call ("filename") throws error - "Error in .Call("filename") : C symbol name "filename" not in load table"

Comment: According to this discussion https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-May/060948.html you could try `.Fortran("filename_")`. But this is only a guess

Comment: @d_1999 Fortran appended "_" after the routine name.Thanks for the help.

Comment: @curiousprogrammer if that is the solution to your problem then you may wish to answer your own question.